# End condition of an IF loop that depends on a 3D array

Tags: c, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program which will move a particle about a cube, either left,right,up,down, back or forward depending on the value randomly generator by the program. The particle is able to move with cube of dimensions LxLxL. I wish the program to stop when the particle has been to all possible sites and the number of jumps taken output.

Currently I am doing this using an array[i][j][k] and when the particle has been to a position, changing the value of the array at that corresponding point to 0. However, in my IF loop I have to type out every possible combination of i,j and k in order to say if they are all equal to 0 the program should end. Would there be a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Beth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I'm assuming the `if` in question is the one contained within the triple nested loop who's body sets `finish=1;`. The better way of doing this is to set a your flag before the loop, beginning with a true value then setting it to false and breaking if you encounter a value other then zero. Your if statement becomes much simpler, like this;

```
int finish =1; // start with a true value

//loops are untouched so still got the for i and for j above this
for(k = 0; k < 15; k++)
{
    if (list[i][j][k] != 0)
    {
         finish = 0;
         break;
    }
 }

// outside all the loops
return finish;
```

I think this is what you're asking for but if not please edit your question to clarify. I'm not sure if there is some technical name for this concept but the idea is to choose your initial truth value based on what's most efficient. Given you have a 15x15x15 array and a single non-zero value means false, it's much better to begin with true and break as soon as you encounter a value that makes your statement false. Trying to go in the other direction is far more complicated and far less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add your `list[i][j][k]` to a collection every time `list[i][j][k]=0`. Then at the end of your program, check for the collection's length. If it's of the right length, then terminate..

Comment: Or use a counter that gets incremented only when a) a cell is entered and b) `list[i][j][k]==0`, which is drastically less memory consuming. Compare the counter to the total number of cells to determine if you have been everywhere. Which is in principle the same as Minh's answer